# How to convert multiple png to one DICOM? ImageMagick?

Tags: linux, imagemagick, png, mogrify

I am converting DICOM to PNG but i got multiple PNG. I want to convert thos emultiple PNG to one DICOM?
`mogrify --adjoin -format  dcm  PNG-images/0002-*`

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum Questions about **ImageMagick** are perfectly legitimate on Stack Overflow - there are several associated, valid tags with over 8,000 questions tagged as such.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with DICOM format and whether it is able to hold multiple images in a single file, however I do note that it is listed as *readable* and not *writeable* by **ImageMagick** here... https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: @MarkSetchell is correct. DICOM is just embedded JPEG images encapsulated with medical device metadata + telemetries. ImageMagick can extract the images, but can not emulate proprietary hardware.

Comment: DICOM is read only in ImageMagick